# How to wrap content of flexbox in row layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a multiple line sentence to display. It consists of several parts.

I use flex layout like the following code:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1. </div>
  <div>A long sentance which will take multiple lines.</div>
  <div>(another sentence)</div>
</div>
```

But it's not what I expected. I want the sentence displayed like this:

```
1. A long sentance which will 
take multiple lines.(another 
sentence)
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: don't use flexbox, and replace div with span

Comment: Why are you using flex box for this?

Comment: replace to <span> get same result. @TemaniAfif

Comment: and *don't use flexbox*

Comment: Then it displays in one line. How can I make a wrap? @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace you `div` with a `span` and get rid of the flexbox related styles

```
<div class="container">
  <span>1. </span>
  <span>A long sentence which will take multiple lines.</span>
  <span>(another sentence)</span>
</div>
```

If you plan to have some paddings applied, set the display to `inline-block`

Answer (score 1):

Flex-wrap would not work with this way because your second div has already bigger width size than 100% of your container div so it pushs second div in second line.